# How to rename File From filepath in Android?

Tags: android, file, path, rename

I have Path Which is stored into one variable That is

### String Path:

> String filepath="/mnt/sdcard/DCIM/Camera/1396854069062.jpg";

Now i want to rename only file that is **1396854069062.jpg** I Reilly don't have any idea for how to do that.

### My Code Is:

```
File sdcard = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory();
File from = new File(sdcard, filePath);
File to = new File(sdcard, "RChat_Rename.jpg";
from.renameTo(to);
```

Any help will b appreciated.

Thank You

Comment: Post the code what you have tried.

Comment: @InnocentKiller answer is perfect +1 for that..@Nirav Dabhi have you added READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE and WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE permissions?

Comment: yes I had already given the permisson you can see my code in my edited question

Answer (score 6):

Try this way,

```
File sdcard = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory();
File from = new File(sdcard,"/1396854069062.jpg");
File to = new File(sdcard,"test.jpg");
from.renameTo(to);
```

Do not forget to add below permission in android manifest file

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
```

**Edit**

```
String filepath= Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + "/DCIM/Camera/";
File from = new File(filepath,"1396854069062.jpg");
File to = new File(filepath,"test.jpg");
from.renameTo(to);
```

Comment: Don't forget to add accessing SD card permission in manifest @NiravDabhi other wise it won't work

Comment: Have you added `<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />` this permission in manifest.

Comment: Yes I had added the permission but the Result is same

Comment: No just file didnt renamed

Comment: Are you using the method within "try catch" or alone ?

Comment: Indeed it does and if it doesn't show you an error like NullPointException then it's not something related to the code that innocentkiller posted

Comment: Yes please see my code in the question My method is in try catch block.

Comment: Okey in that case if the code didn't work it will not show the error because it's try . I'm not an expert but can you try using it without try catch and then give us the error log that you get on LogCat ?

Comment: @NiravDabhi  What does renameTo() return when you run it?? true or false??

Comment: I think Hamid got it because in this answer you didn't access the "/DCIM/Camera/" folder . Try Hamid's code and tell us what's the result

Comment: Acctully my whole path store in the variable. which means when i capture image that should be not the system name.

Comment: @NiravDabhi, take a `String` variable instead of `File` for getting SDcard path and then try.

Comment: @NiravDabhi, Still it is the same? Update me whether it is working or not.

Comment: Yes dude its still same. But +1 for your effort. FilePath is dynamic means it is not fixed that user will Pick the image from Camera only. Then how can i do that?

Comment: Then you have to use `onActivityResult` and return a path from there and then apply this rename.

Comment: @NiravDabhi, you want to rename last captured image every time, Is this you want to say?

Comment: @NiravDabhi, what i am asking is you want to get the path of last captured image everytime right? Is this what you are asking?

Comment: Yes You are right I want path of last captured image

Comment: Okay, for that you have to use `onActivityResult` as i already told you and use `Uri audioUri = data.getData(); String absolutepath = getRealPathFromURI(audioUri);` this inside it.

Answer (score 4):

Try as below...

```
File fileDir = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() +"/DCIM/Camera/";
File from = new File(fileDir, "1396854069062.jpg");
File to = new File(fileDir, "RChat_Rename.jpg";
from.renameTo(to);
```

Comment: Cant Convert fileDir to string. :(

Comment: But the file is Dynamic and it's not fix that user will pick the image from camera only then how can I do that?

Comment: So, you want rename a picture which is taken from camera, right?

Comment: then you should give a name to the image to when you start the camera to capture that image.

Comment: yes dear I got the path of the image which is choosed by user.

Comment: It's creating new file