# Unable to rename videomodal file in androidX java

Tags: java, android, rename

Am trying to implement a file rename option so i tried

```
confirmEdit.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                try {
                    renameFile(filePath, editFileName.getText().toString());
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }

            public void renameFile(File toBeRenamed, String new_name)
                    throws IOException {
                //need to be in the same path
                File fileWithNewName = new File(toBeRenamed.getParent(), new_name);
                if (fileWithNewName.exists()) {
                    throw new IOException("file exists");
                }
                // Rename file (or directory)
                boolean success = toBeRenamed.renameTo(fileWithNewName);
                if (!success) {
                    // File was not successfully renamed
                    Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Failed", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
            }
        });
```

and i get Not success i also added `<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" /> <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />`

and followed [android, How to rename a file?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10424997/android-how-to-rename-a-file) and tried couple of answer and all fails. And even i have tried multiple topics like below

1. [How to rename File From filepath in Android?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22911025/how-to-rename-file-from-filepath-in-android)
2. [How to rename a file on sdcard with Android application?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2896733/how-to-rename-a-file-on-sdcard-with-android-application)
3. [How to rename a file in internal Storage?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51773785/how-to-rename-a-file-in-internal-storage)

Why am not able to rename file, Or what wrong am doing ?

Comment: You need approval for permission from the user

Comment: @Vlad yes i have added `READ` and `WRITE` permission in manifest.

Comment: on device also, not just in manifest

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I added `<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />`

and uninstalled app, and then reinstalled.

and i was able to rename file, And later i found i didn't enable write permission on my mobile device.